# [Py3,BS]How can I get the value of a div element

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hell-o!
I want to get the text "accepted" inside of the div as a string using Python and BeautifulSoup.

```
<div class="wordlist-item">accepted</div>
```

Using the following code the output is not what I wanted.

```
table = soup2.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "wordlist-item"})
```

Output:

```
<div class="wordlist-item">accepted</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `.text` or `.get_text()`:

```
html_doc = """
    <div class="wordlist-item">accepted</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(soup.find("div", class_="wordlist-item").text)
```

Prints:

```
accepted
```

---

Note: When you use `.findAll()`, you have to iterate the results:

```
table = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "wordlist-item"})
for div in table:
    print(div.text)
```